# Is independence preserved after conditioning?

Tags: probability

I'm wondering if the following holds :

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,P,F)$ where the filtration $F$ is given by $F=\{F_0,F_1,\ldots,F_T\}$ and two $F_T $-measurable claims $X$ and $Y$. If we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, are they also independent under $F_t$ with $t<T$?

Otherwise stated, does the following hold : 
$X$ independent of $Y$ => $X$ independent of $Y$ given $F_t$

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Possibly related: Let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be independent random variables, and let $Z_3:=Z_1+Z_2$. Then $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent, but they are not independent given $Z_3$.

Comment: I assume that $X$ and $Y$ are events in your probability space (so they are in the collection of events $F$). Independence means that $P[X \cap Y]=P[X]P[Y]$.  This has nothing to do with particular sub-sigma algebras $F_t \subseteq F$.  These would come into play if you start using conditional probability or conditional expectation.  The angryavian comment perhaps answers your question if you define $F_0=\sigma(Z_1+Z_2)$ and $F_1=F=\sigma(Z_1,Z_2)$ (where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent random variables as in angryavian's example).

Comment: Thanks both of you for your answers ! In fact, I was wondering if E(XY)=E(X)E(Y) because X and Y are independent, remains true if we use conditional expectations E(XY given Ft)= E(X given Ft) E(Y given Ft). I think it's not true due to the example of @angryavian